The equation of the largest circle with center (1,0) which is inscribed in the ellipse $x^2 + 4y^2 = 16$.
The largest circle with center $(1,0)$ which can be drawn inside an ellipse with equation $x^2 + 4y^2 = 16$ is.....

Welcome on MSE. You should consider including what you tried so far. For example, what equation is satisfied by a point $(x,y)$ lying on the circle of radius $r$ and center $(1,0)$?

The largest circle will touch the ellipse, hence there will be only one solution for
\begin{align}
(x+1)^2+y^2&=r^2\\
x^2+4y^2&=16
\end{align}
in the upper right quadrant ($x,y>0$).
Substituting $y^2=4-x^2/4$ in the first equation we get
$$
\frac34 x^2+2x+4=r^2-1\quad \Longrightarrow
\quad
3x^2+8x+(20-4r^2)=0.
$$
For this equation to have ONE solution you need that its discriminant is $0$, i.e.
$$
(8/2)^2-3\times(20-4r^2)=0
$$
i.e. $r=\sqrt{11/3}$.


Equation of circle with centre $(1,0)$ can be assumed as $(x-1)^2+y^2=r^2$
Solving with $x^2+4y^2=16$ we get a quadratic in $x$ :
$(x-1)^2+\frac{16-x^2}{4}=r^2$
i.e. $\frac{3}{4}x^2-2x+5-r^2=0$.
Since circle is inscribed $Discriminant=0\Rightarrow 4-3(5-r^2)=0\Rightarrow r^2=\frac{11}{3}$
$\Rightarrow r=\sqrt{\frac{11}{3}}=1.91$
